# How to save video to phone gallery - Dio/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm trying to save the video in the phone gallery (downloaded using dio package) To get the path, I'm using path provider package but unable to save it in the phone gallery

Here is my code

```
void downloadVideo() async {

  var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

                      final dio = Dio();

                      dio.download(
                          'video_url',
                          '${dir!.path}/video.mp4', // saving path, I'm trying to save it in phone gallery
                          onReceiveProgress: (actualBytes, totalBytes){
                            var percentage = actualBytes/totalBytes*100;

                    
                          }
                      );
}
```

Note:- I'm aware of gallery_saver package but I need to achieve this using dio and path provider

Comment: `gallery_saver` and `image_gallery_saver` are not just a package but plugins. It means that they are achieving this using native codes. I believe that you need to write native codes if you don't want to use these plugins. Otherwise, please check the answer below that I have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already have the saving directory. You can use plugins like [image_gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver) and [gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) to save your downloaded video to the gallery.

If you use `image_gallery_saver`, the saving code would be similar to this:

```
await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(finalVideoPath);
```

**And don't forget to delete the video in the download path after saving the video successfully to the gallery.**

Final code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> downloadVideo() async {
  final appDocDirectory = await getAppDocDirectory();

  final finalVideoPath = join(
    appDocDirectory.path,
    'Video-${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4',
  );

  final dio = Dio();

  await dio.download(
    'video_url',
    finalVideoPath,
    onReceiveProgress: (actualBytes, totalBytes) {
      final percentage = actualBytes / totalBytes * 100;
    },
  );

  await saveDownloadedVideoToGallery(videoPath: finalVideoPath);
  await removeDownloadedVideo(videoPath: finalVideoPath);
}

Future<Directory> getAppDocDirectory() async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  }

  return (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
}

Future<void> saveDownloadedVideoToGallery({required String videoPath}) async {
  await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(videoPath);
}

Future<void> removeDownloadedVideo({required String videoPath}) async {
  try {
    Directory(videoPath).deleteSync(recursive: true);
  } catch (error) {
    debugPrint('$error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked! But I’m having one silly question, will this download the video for two times? Firstly using dio.download() and then using imagegallerysaver.saveFile()? @BBK

Comment: or it will just take the video from saved directory and save it to the gallery too?

Comment: @shaktigoyal `image_gallery_saver` won't download the file again. You need to provide the location of the video, and it will save the file in the provided directory to the gallery. But the downloaded file will be staying where you download it, so I suggest you delete it if you don't need it anymore. If you have any other questions about this, I would like to help. Hope it helps.

Comment: Lastly, if you use the final code that I have provided in my answer, it already deletes the downloaded file after saving it to the gallery. And the saved video in the gallery will keep staying there. If everything is fine, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: It worked exactly like you have explained and thank you for clearing my doubt! You’re awesome :)